# Is there any api in aws pinpoint for fetching custom events data through postman?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, aws-pinpoint

I'm setting up analytics from aws pinpoint and can not fetch custom events data through any api. The only way I know to fetch data is through aws kinesis stream which can only store data upto 168 hours or 7 days. Is there any api that can fetch pinpoint events data for last 1 year?

The only way I can fetch the data is through aws kinesis, which only stores data upto 168 hours. I have to implement this in node js

Answer (score 2):

Your observation is correct, Amazon Pinpoint is able to act on and report events, but it is not designed to store them. To store, you can link/integrate it with other services specifically designed for that, such as Redshift or DynamoDB (or any other storage mechanism really, inside and outside AWS, even S3 or your own fileshare).
You probably already saw these, but here are some related resources:
set-up doc @ https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/event-streams-setup.html (note that you can use not just Kinesis for delivery, but also Kinesis Data Firehose) and a blog article on Redshift integration @ https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/streaming-events-from-amazon-pinpoint-to-redshift/ (you can follow similar approach as what's described here, but with any other data storage location or service, it does not have to be Redshift, as mentioned).